# No sound in KVM guest

Tags: rhel, windows, audio, kvm

Host : Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.0 (Plow)

guest : Windows 10 Pro

I was not getting any sound from the guest os ( windows 10 ) the audio icon was crossed with red.

```
[munish259272@localhost cache]$ sudo cat /var/log/libvirt/qemu/win10.log | grep -i ich
-global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 \
```

then i added based on the above info i added sound hardware using the KVM gui.
[image]

Here is some more info , am i missing audio driver?

```
[munish259272@localhost cache]$ sudo cat /var/log/libvirt/qemu/win10.log | grep -i audio
-audiodev '{"id":"audio1","driver":"none"}' \
-vnc 127.0.0.1:0,audiodev=audio1 \
-device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0,audiodev=audio1 \
```

[image]

some more info

```
[munish259272@localhost cache]$ pactl list sinks | grep -E "State|Driver|Sink|Ports|analog-ou|node"
Sink #50
    State: RUNNING
    Driver: PipeWire
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "HDA Intel PCH"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        node.driver = "true"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
    Ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (type: Line, priority: 9000, availability group: Legacy 4, available)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, availability group: Legacy 5, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output-lineout
Sink #272
    State: SUSPENDED
    Driver: PipeWire
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        node.name = "alsa_output.usb-Realtek_Realtek_USB2.0_Audio_201405280001-00.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "Realtek USB2.0 Audio"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        node.driver = "true"
        node.max-latency = "65536/48000"
    Ports:
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, availability group: Legacy 2, available)
    Active Port: analog-output-headphones
Sink #488
    State: SUSPENDED
    Driver: PipeWire
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        node.name = "alsa_output.usb-USB_PnP_Sound_Device_USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00.iec958-stereo"
        node.nick = "USB PnP Sound Device"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        node.driver = "true"
    Ports:
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/a/284638